# Showing a system is fully self adjoint for general unmixed boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been asked to look at the following questions and I'm struggling to solve it.

Let $Ly=a_2(x)y''(x)+a_1(x)y'(x)+a_0(x)y(x) , a<x<b$ such that $L^*=L$.

i.e. $L$ is a self adjoint linear operator.

Show that the system is fully self adjoint for general unmixed boundary conditions

$f_1y(a)+f_2y'(a)=0$, $g_1y(b)+g_2y'(b)=0$ where $f_1,f_2,g_1,g_2$ are constants.

So far I've tried to find the adjoint of the linear operator using integration by parts but I'm finding it hard to sort out all the terms because I keep ending up with integrals and differentials of the $a_i(x)$s.

Would anyone be able to help me solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

E.L. Ince, Ordinary Differential Equations, Dover, (1956), Section 9.4, p. 215 gives a thorough and complete discussion. It is a lot of work though but your case is simpler because the boundary conditions are "separated".